# Animation android: why doesn't it do what I want?

Tags: android, animation, translation

I have circular menu like shown on this picture

[image: Circular Menu]

It's a custom view, without any associated layout. All items, the center button and arrows are created programmaticaly.
I'd like to add animation when all items are created, a bit like this library [this library](https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu), that means items have to move from the center to their final position.
Based on the official tutorial, I try something but it does not do what I want.

```
final TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, CompatibilityUtil.screenWidth((Activity) context) / 2,
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, 1,
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, CompatibilityUtil.screenHeight((Activity)context) / 2,
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, 1);
        translateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
        translateAnimation.setFillAfter( true );

        // start the animation
        elements[i].startAnimation(translateAnimation);  //element[i] est le bouton i
        elements[i].setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Instead of appearing their turn, the whole menu is already done and translates from the bottom corner till its final good position.

What's wrong?
Please, help me !